# Is it possible to call sweetalerts from within main electron thread?

Tags: electron, sweetalert2

I tried calling a sweetalert within the main electron thread but the sweetalert doesn't appear.  Is it possible for this to work?

```
const Swal = require('sweetalert2');

Swal.fire('blah', 'test', 'error');
```

Comment: in main thread it will not possible

Comment: You can still send an ipc message to your renderer and use swal on the render side

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you should use this:

https://electron.guide/electron-alert/

"ElectronAlert is a beautiful and developer-friendly alert for Electron applications. It is powered by SweetAlert2 and works directly from the main process."